# React Native TouchableOpacity scrolling

Tags: reactjs, scroll, native, touchableopacity

I have an old issue with scrolling some content inside TouchableOpacity (react-native). I've been trying to find any solution for months but nothing worked together with onPress/onPressIn/Out handlers. Any ideas?

```
<TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={1}
  delayPressIn={1}
  onPress={handlePress}
  onPressIn={handlePressIn}
  onLongPress={handleLongPress}
  onPressOut={handlePressOut}>
    <ScrollView>
      {/* some content to be scrolled here */}
    </ScrollView>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **TouchableOpacity** inside the **Scrollview**

```
<ScrollView>
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
      delayPressIn={1}
      onPress={handlePress}
      onPressIn={handlePressIn}
      onLongPress={handleLongPress}
      onPressOut={handlePressOut}>
        
          {/* component to be displayed */}
       
   </TouchableOpacity>
   <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
      delayPressIn={1}
      onPress={handlePress}
      onPressIn={handlePressIn}
      onLongPress={handleLongPress}
      onPressOut={handlePressOut}>
        
          {/* component to be displayed */}
       
    </TouchableOpacity>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have already refactored my app in this way and it really work. Thanks for advice anyway!